# What type of light do White's tree frogs need?

Tags: terrariums, lighting, frogs, amphibians

We have had a White's tree frog for a few months now.  We currently have a [ZooMed ReptiSun 5.0 mini compact fluorescent bulb](http://www.zoomed.com/db/products/EntryDetail.php?EntryID=1516&DatabaseID=2&SearchID=20) on top of the terrarium that we keep on during the day, and no light at night.  However, I've received conflicting information on whether the White's tree frog needs UV light and what the requirements are.  I'm wondering if my frog needs UV light or if the UV light might be damaging his eyes.  He spends most of the day stuck to the side of the glass sleeping with his eyes pointed at the light.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because these frogs are [nocturnal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nocturnality), there are no special lighting requirements. Exposure to UVB is not necessary, although some exposure won't hurt.

> White's Tree Frogs need a cycle of 12 hours of light followed by 12 hours of darkness. Low amounts of UVB light, like from a ReptiSun 2.0 bulb, may be beneficial. Use a full spectrum fluorescent light and an incandescent bulb during the day. Infrared or black bulbs can be used at night, if necessary to maintain proper temperatures. We recommend using a timer to maintain proper light cycles. Source : [How to Create the Ideal White's Tree Frog Habitat](http://www.drsfostersmith.com/pic/article.cfm?aid=2385)

Comment: Also: the UVA/UVB will help the frog assimilate certain vitamins. I don't have Whites' but Thelodermas' and give them a supplement of calcium and carotene via their food since I have read that the UVA/UVB lights help them to assimilate those.